# Working code stopped working when reloading rStudio

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I have several chunks of code that use pipes and many of them have stopped working when I reloaded rStudio that did not happen before.  The following code was working before:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "A","B" ,"A" ,"B"), b = c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6))
df %>% count(a)
```

but now it tells me `Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"` has to be written as:

`count(df$a)`

or:

`df %>% count(vars="a")`

any ideas on what I could have done?  rStudio says it's up to date, I'm using R 3.6.1 and I also tried reinstalling dplyr.

EDIT:
here is information from sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.4.0     lubridate_1.7.4 tidyr_1.0.0     plyr_1.8.4     
[5] dplyr_0.8.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       rstudioapi_0.10  knitr_1.26       magrittr_1.5    
 [5] tidyselect_0.2.5 xtable_1.8-4     R6_2.4.1         rlang_0.4.2     
 [9] fastmap_1.0.1    stringr_1.4.0    tools_3.6.1      xfun_0.11       
[13] htmltools_0.4.0  assertthat_0.2.1 digest_0.6.23    tibble_2.1.3    
[17] lifecycle_0.1.0  crayon_1.3.4     later_1.0.0      purrr_0.3.3     
[21] promises_1.1.0   vctrs_0.2.0      rsconnect_0.8.15 zeallot_0.1.0   
[25] mime_0.7         glue_1.3.1       stringi_1.4.3    compiler_3.6.1  
[29] pillar_1.4.2     backports_1.1.5  httpuv_1.5.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you add your `sessionInfo()`? Do you have any function defined as `a` in `.Globalenv`?

Comment: I've added it above.  `a` is not used anywhere except in this example.

Comment: Somehow you have loading `plyr` after loading `dplyr` (as `plyr` is [4] in other attached packages) so `count` is using `plyr::count`. Either use `df %>% dplyr::count(a)` or make sure to restart a fresh session and that plyr is either loaded before dplyr or not loaded at all and then run

Comment: This was it.  Thank you both so much!